# Date time no atribute microseconds

Tags: pandas

I have this:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.003
1900-01-01 00:00:00.003
1900-01-01 00:00:00.007
1900-01-01 00:00:00.007
1900-01-01 00:00:00.011
1900-01-01 00:00:00.011
1900-01-01 00:00:00.015
1900-01-01 00:00:00.015
```

I converted my df to datetime like this:

```
x = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I am trying to create an accumulative array of the microseconds, like this:

```
    003
    003
    007
    007
    011
    011
    015
    015
```

But I am getting the following message:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'microsecond'
```

I am trying something like this `x.microsecond`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
x = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
x.dt.microsecond
```

If you want in that form you could really just get the final 3 characters:

```
df['Time'].str[-3:]
    003
    003
    007
    007
    011
    011
    015
    015
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.dt.microsecond`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.microsecond.html) without `s`:

```
x = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.microsecond / 1000

print (x)
0     3.0
1     3.0
2     7.0
3     7.0
4    11.0
5    11.0
6    15.0
7    15.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```